# Inconvertable types Cannot Cast ArrayList<Parcelable> to

Tags: java, android

Line with error:

```
PersonList persons;
persons = (PersonList) intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_PERSON_LIST);
```

How PersonList is declared:

```
public class PersonList extends ArrayList<Person> {
```

How Person is declared:

```
public class Person extends CommonObject implements Parcelable {
```

Since PersonList extends ArrayList (Person) and Person implements Parcelable not sure why this doesn't work.

Comment: What is the type of `persons`?

Comment: PersonList obviously

Comment: correct i edited to add that

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in this way.

```
ArrayList<Person>  l = ...;
PersonList p = (PersonList) l; // Not possible

PersonList p = ...;
ArrayList<Person> l = p; // This will work
```

- A `PersonList` **is** an `ArrayList` of `Person`
- An `ArrayList` of `Person` **is not always** a `PersonList`